# Error importing iTunes Media into Banshee Media Player - Unable to map iTunes URI to local URI

Tags: banshee

I'm trying to import my iTunes library into Banshee. Unfortunately, I'm getting a message on a number of tracks that says "Unable to map iTunes URI to local URI."

It seems to be showing up on entire albums rather than random individual tracks.

What does it mean and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't use Banshee or iTunes, so I don't feel like I'm an authority on this but check [this forum post](http://banshee-media-player.2283330.n4.nabble.com/iTunes-library-import-ERROR-td3492260.html#a3494885). This person got the same error message as you and determined that Banshee didn't have the correct path to the music files. He was able to correct that problem and Banshee was then able to locate his music. Well, hopefully this helps you out!

Comment: That was indeed the problem. Specifically, the capitalization (or lack thereof) of certain letters. Interestingly enough, I had other tracks with an incorrect path that showed an error message of "File does not exist."

Answer (score 1):

Follow these directions to copy and convert a Windows iTunes library including music and playlists to Ubuntu linux for use with Banshee.

1. Copy the `C:/Users/<yourName>/Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/Music` directory from Windows to Ubuntu `/home/<yourName>/Music` directory.
2. Copy the Windows `iTunes Library.xml` file to the same directory in Linux.
3. Open a Linux terminal window and execute the following changing  with your user name (it converts all the Windows paths to Linux paths and allows you to import not only music but playlists as well.):

`cd /home/<yourName>/Music`

`sed -i 's/C:\/Users\/<yourName>\/Music\/iTunes\/iTunes%20Media/home\/<yourName>\/Music/g' ./*Library.xml`

4. Run Banshee, right click Music and Import Media. Choose the `/home/<yourName>/Music` folder and import.

You should see your music as well as your playlists imported.